# Term used for notification on your device from a website

Tags: ux-field, copywriting

What would you call the notifications from a website on your laptops/desktops/tablets?
A. Web notifications
B. Desktop notifications
C. Browser notifications

Comment: The spec is titled [Web Notifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/), and I've also seen the term [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/) used frequently. Either of those are probably a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming this is a label you're going to add to the notification, something users are going to see.

Not B. If I'm getting a notification on my desktop the label doesn't need to tell me that it's a desktop notification. "Desktop" doesn't help me understand what the notification refers to.

A surprising number of users I've spoken to don't know what a browser is. So not C.

Therefore, use A.

---

If you're looking for a label used only in a technical document that users won't ever see, then B might be the way to go. That label tells the reader that these are notifications from the website that appear on the desktop, outside the normal context of this document.